# Dataframe equals compares false but each column compares true

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I just compared 2 dataframes (which have the same columns) as follows:

```
In [21]: df1.equals(df2)
Out[21]: False

In [22]: for col in df1.columns:
    ...:     print(df1[col].equals(df2[col]))
    ...:     
    ...:         
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True

In [23]: df1.index.equals(df2.index)
```

Since every column is equal, how is it that `df1.equals(df2)` compares `False`?

I'm not sure if this is the culprit, but when I printed `df1.columns` and `df2.columns`, the ordering is different. Though I thought dataframe `equals` check is agnostic to the ordering of the columns?

Comment: `df2` has additional column that dont exist in `df1`. In this situation, it is possible.

Comment: @PandaKim As I stated in the OP, they have the same columns

Comment: even if the order is different, it returns False. I think questions that can be checked by yourself should be asked with [a minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),  rather than questions that do not fit Stack Overflow.  you can chk by using `reindex`

Comment: @PandaKim not sure what you're talking about? this question is clearly relevant for SO. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html doesn't mention anything about the ordering of the columns in the equality check

Comment: If you had asked how to make the order the same, you could have made us reproducible and checked your question yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Or, if you had only made an example that changed the order while trying to make us reproducible, you could have checked it yourself. so it seems like an inappropriate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I thought DataFrame's [`equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) check is agnostic to the ordering of the columns..*

No, order **matters** here.

In your case, the comparison `df1.equals(df2)` returns `False` because at some point, [`pandas.Index.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.equals.html) (*thar is order-sensitive*) is run under the hood to compare between the headers of both DataFrames and the latter checks if [`array_equivalent`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8df36a2f9f787af7fcc08326c6d7b3456b3ff0b7/pandas/core/dtypes/missing.py#L466) :

```
# left  : array(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], dtype=object)
# right : array(['col3', 'col2', 'col1'], dtype=object)
```

Reproducible example :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": [4, 5, 6], "col3": [7, 8, 9]})
df2 = df1.sample(frac=1, axis=1, random_state=0) # ["col3", "col2", "col1"]

df1.equals(df2) # False

for col in df1.columns:
    print(df1[col].equals(df2[col]))

# True
# True
# True
```